# DHTMLX Scheduler Recurring Events Controller Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx

I need to do DHTMLX Recurring events in my MVC3 project. For recurring events i need to setup my controller code to store and retrieve the extra DB values like rec_type, event_pid.

I have done the basic coding for simple events. But I dont know how to write for reccurring events. In the demo site itself showing it on PHP. This is the Tutorial link ([Here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler%3arecurring_events)). Please provide me the logic for C# environment.

**Simple Event Create / Update / Delete**

```
    public ActionResult Save(Event changedEvent, FormCollection actionValues)
    {
        var a = "Z";
        String action_type = actionValues["!nativeeditor_status"];
        Int64 source_id = Int64.Parse(actionValues["id"]);
        Int64 target_id = source_id;
        string category = actionValues["category"];
        string title = actionValues["title"];
        string description = actionValues["text"];
        if (actionValues["rec_type"] != "")
        {
            changedEvent.Rec_Type = actionValues["rec_type"];
        }
        else
            changedEvent.Rec_Type = "";
        if (actionValues["event_length"] != "")
        {
            changedEvent.Event_Length = Convert.ToInt32(actionValues["event_length"]);
        }
        else
            changedEvent.Event_Length = 0;
        if (actionValues["event_pid"] != "")
        {
            changedEvent.Event_Pid = Convert.ToInt16(actionValues["event_pid"]);
        }
        else
            changedEvent.Event_Pid = 0;
        String catg = category;
        changedEvent.UserId = 1;
        changedEvent.Category = catg;
        changedEvent.Description = description;
        changedEvent.Title = title;
        try
        {
            switch (action_type)
            {
                case "inserted":
                    changedEvent.UserId = 1;
                    changedEvent.Category = catg;
                    db.Events.AddObject(changedEvent);

                    break;
                case "deleted":
                    changedEvent = db.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == source_id);
                    db.Events.DeleteObject(changedEvent);
                    break;
                default: // "updated"
                    db.Events.Attach(changedEvent);
                    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(changedEvent, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    break;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            target_id = changedEvent.Id;
        }
        catch
        {
            action_type = "error";
        }

        return View(new CalendarActionResponseModel(action_type, source_id, target_id, catg));
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving of the data should be the same as for simple events, except that you'll render 3 extra fields - event_length, event_pid, rec_type. The default value of rec_type(which will mean that event is not recurring) is empty string of null

As for saving, check "Controller changes" paragraph of this article, it might help
http://scheduler-net.com/docs/recurring_events.html#controller_changes

Although it targets dhtmlxScheduler for .Net, which is separate component, the processing logic is the same.

In general, saving of recurring events will work the same way as for simple ones(the same method could process simple and recurring events), but you'll need to add additional logic for the following cases:

1. if an event with (**rec_type == "none"**) was inserted - the response must have "deleted" status;
2. if an event with (**!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rec_type) && rec_type != "none"**)  was updated or deleted - all records with the related event_pid must be deleted;
3. if an event with non-default **event_pid** value was deleted - it need to be updated with **rec_type = "none"** instead of deleting.

**UPD**, Code Sample

The final code might look like following(I didn't actually run it, so it may contain some mistakes),

All changes, compared to simple version, is the "deleteRelated" method(note that if deleteRelated returns true, switch-case should be omitted) and checking of the Rec_Type in the "inserted" case

```
public ActionResult Save(Event changedEvent, FormCollection actionValues){
    String action_type = actionValues["!nativeeditor_status"];
    Int64 source_id = Int64.Parse(actionValues["id"]);
    Int64 target_id = source_id;
    string category = actionValues["category"];
    string title = actionValues["title"];
    string description = actionValues["text"];


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionValues["rec_type"]))
        changedEvent.Rec_Type = actionValues["rec_type"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionValues["event_length"]))
        changedEvent.Event_Length = Convert.ToInt32(actionValues["event_length"]);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionValues["event_pid"]))
        changedEvent.Event_Pid = Convert.ToInt16(actionValues["event_pid"]);

    String catg = category;
    changedEvent.UserId = 1;
    changedEvent.Category = catg;
    changedEvent.Description = description;
    changedEvent.Title = title;
    try
    {
        if (!deleteRelated(action_type, changedEvent, db))//some logic specific for recurring events
        {
            switch (action_type)
            {
                case "inserted":
                    changedEvent.UserId = 1;
                    changedEvent.Category = catg;
                    db.Events.AddObject(changedEvent);

                    if (changedEvent.Rec_Type == "none")
                        action_type = "deleted";//if an event with (rec_type == "none") was inserted - the response must have "deleted" status

                    break;
                case "deleted":
                    changedEvent = db.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == source_id);
                    db.Events.DeleteObject(changedEvent);
                    break;
                default: // "updated"
                    db.Events.Attach(changedEvent);
                    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(changedEvent, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    break;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        target_id = changedEvent.Id;
    }
    catch
    {
        action_type = "error";
    }

    return View(new CalendarActionResponseModel(action_type, source_id, target_id, catg));
}
protected bool deleteRelated(string action_type, Event changedEvent, RecurringEntities db)//
{
    bool finished = false;
    if ((action_type == "deleted" || action_type == "updated")
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(changedEvent.Rec_Type))
    {
        //if an event with (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rec_type) && rec_type != "none") was updated or deleted - all records with the related event_pid must be deleted;
        db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Films WHERE Event_Pid = {0}", changedEvent.Id);
    }
    if (action_type == "deleted"
            && (changedEvent.Event_Pid != 0 && changedEvent.Event_Pid != default<Int16>))
    {
        //if an event with non-default event_pid value was deleted - it need to be updated with rec_type = "none" instead of deleting.
        var item = db.Events.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == changedEvent.Id);
        item.Rec_Type = "none";
        db.SaveChanges();
        finished = true; //in this case no more processing is needed
    }
    return finished;
}
```

Comment: In the dhtmlxScheduler for .Net sample tutorial page they have used built in dll libary and functions to do some extraction of values. I couldn't make my own logic for Lightbox settings. can you just provide me in more detail. I ll be attaching my simple event code here.